# faded/grayscale printing with Epson WF-4630

Tags: 16.04, printing, epson

I'm getting a grayscale/faded effect on all colors, including black, when printing on an Epson WF-4630. 
Any way to resolve this issue? I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
Thanks,

Comment: Not to be glib but have you checked the ink level in your cartridges?

Answer (score 0):

Haha. Yes. And printed the same documents from elsewhere and I am getting a big difference in saturation and clarity.